# Mapping a csv file in R

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm trying to map crime incidents in Boston. I converted the lat/long to simple feature points but when I plotted it, I only got two points. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

```
crimedata = read.csv("2019 Crime Incidents.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
points = st_as_sf(crimedata, coords = c("Lat", "Long"), crs = 4326)
plot(points$geometry, pch=16, col="navy")
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to plot the points onto a map you need add an additional package.  There are many available options for example: tmap or ggmap.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your problem is the 'two points' bit, you should examine your geometry column to check that there really are multiple crime locations (eg your data isn't attributed to one of two police districts or something). Then you could try adding a map for scale as suggested, because there could be some erroneous point on the other side of the world, forcing a scale that makes all your real points appear coincident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot the points on top of a map:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)

points <- tibble(
  lon = c(-100, -90),
  lat = c(40, 40),
  value = c("A", "B")
)
c(left = -125, bottom = 25.75, right = -67, top = 49) %>%
  get_stamenmap(zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-lite") %>%
  ggmap() +
    geom_point(
      data = points,
      mapping = aes(color = value),
      size = 7
    )
```

[image]